# Visual Studio 2015 Community License update fails in Samba NT4 Domain due to proxy/firewall

Tags: visual-studio, samba, license-key, vs-community-edition

First off, I read all other Questions, that relate to this, I did an extensive google search on this topic and could not get a working answer.

I installed the Community Version of Visual Studio 2015 in mid November and been using it since then. After finishing my project, I went back to pen and paper for new formulas and noe came back to implement all those neat things.

Now it says, that my trial license has expired and should be renewed. I already read, I should use my MicrosoftAccount to do that, and proceeded by doing that. 
[Now this happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGtHR.png)

It says, I should check firewall and prxoy settings and I read about contactiong the administrator. So that, what I did, but he says, there is no proxy, no block by firewall or anything else. 
When running VS as administrator (after entering my credentials) I can create new projects and debug existing ones, so no problem there. However I can not use the program as normal user.

I read somewhere here to try repair it via systemcontrol, but that did not work either. 
Does anyone has a solution?

In addition: There is also no "Enter License Key here" field, so that is also not an option.

---

(several Days later)

Halleluja, I found the answer! After digging through some Microsoft Help-Forums, I came upon [this Thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c544822-fbc5-4e93-956c-8992020b0024/domainjoined-accounts-cant-renew-visual-studio-2015-community-license?forum=vssetup), that not only perfectly describes my problem, but also gives a solution. So dear visitor from the future, who googled the problem and came upen this Stackoverflow Question: Follow the link above!

Comment: [sf] is possibly a better fit for this question.

Comment: Since I found most questions regarding this problem here, I thought,it would be a good idea to ask this one here too. Is there a way to migrate this question?

Comment: Moderators can migrate it if they think it is appropriate, otherwise, someone may still answer it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work

Answer (score 1):

So, after sniffing packets harder than a drug addict, trying to find a difference in TLS exchanges between my computer and VS licensing server when using a domain account and when a using local account, and noticing no difference, I recalled why I had pushed this hypothesis to the side: our network supports TLS 1.2 perfectly well, as I can connect to TLS 1.2-only remote hosts without any issue.

This means the issue lies elsewhere, and is caused by Visual Studio treating domain accounts and local accounts differently when trying to renew licensing information.
The good news is I've found why and how to fix it.

I recalled that earlier this year, when we upgraded our commercial department from Windows 7 to Windows 10, they all encountered issues while trying to configure their mail accounts on Microsoft Outlook: an unknown error 0x8004011c. If you search around for it you'll quickly find that this only happens when using domain accounts and not when using local accounts (sounds familiar, heh?). The fix to bypass this issue is to set a specific Windows cryptography-related registry key.

When digging a little deeper, you can find that this fix is related to KB 3000850 (which I sadly cannot link to due to my account not being verified) and is actually described in the "Known issues" section, as well as in Samba-related documentation ("Required Settings for Samba NT4 Domains").
In short: Windows 8.1+ clients (with KB3000850) joined to an NT-Style domain are not able to use Windows Credential Manager. This doesn't occur when not using a NT-Style domain. The fix seems to globally authorize using Windows Credential Manager whatever the domain context.

So, to wrap it up, if:

- You have a NT-Style domain (such as when using a Samba domain controller)
- You have Windows 8.1 or later
  vYou encounter issues when renewing your Visual Studio license
- Then, set the following registry key:

  ```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb]
  "ProtectionPolicy"=dword:00000001
  ```

This solved the issue on our domain, for all machines and accounts tested.

As to why Visual Studio 2015 needs to use Windows Credential Manager and not Visual Studio 2013, someone from Microsoft will have to chime in there to explain because I have no clue.

Comment: Thank you for adding this as an answer!

Comment: By "NT-Style" you mean non-Windows that is compatible with NT 4.0? NT 4 came out in 1995. Shouldn't you upgrade your domain to something more up-to-date instead of weakening security ? In fact, the Samba NT4 page you linked to gives exactly this advice: `Anyway, consider migrating to a Samba Active Directory (AD) to avoid problems if a future update from Microsoft disables or removes the unsupported NT4 features`

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old Samba server that uses unsupported features. NT4 came out in 1995. Active Directory didn't exist back then. A *lot* has changed in the last *20 years*, including strengthening security and gradually removing older, less secure features like LanMan and NT4 domains.

Instead of weakening security, you should follow the advice posted in the page you linked, [Required Settings for Samba NT4 Domains](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Required_Settings_for_Samba_NT4_Domains):

> Microsoft discontinued the official support for NT4 domains in their Windows operating systems. ... Anyway, consider migrating to a Samba Active Directory (AD) to avoid problems if a future update from Microsoft disables or removes the unsupported NT4 features.